# SQL Server stored procedure: UPDATE with lowest value, else INSERT if there's already a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

Migrating 20K rows or so at once, hopefully. Been away from SQL for over 10 years and struggling.

I may be going about this entirely wrong. Need to update `Table1.Value2` with the lowest value from `Table2.Value1`, unless there's already a `Value2`. If the latter, I need to insert a row with that value as `Table1.Value1`.

`Table1.Value1` is the lowest value of each ID for the row. `Value2` needs to be the next lowest.

Current Table1:

```
ID1, 123, [empty]
ID4, 111, [empty]
```

Current Table2:

```
ID1, 224
ID1, 331
ID4, 210
ID4, 551
```

Table1 - desired state:

```
ID1, 123, 224
ID1, 331, [empty]
ID4, 111, 210
ID4, 551, [empty]
```

Table2 - desired state:

```
[empty]
```

Here's what I tried and the Update section works correctly. Insert never works. I think I coded myself into a corner.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Broken
AS
    --DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @ID INT,
            @Value1 INT,
            @Value2 INT,
            @tmpValue INT

    --DECLARE COUNTER
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1

    --DECLARE CURSOR FOR QUERY
    DECLARE cTable1 CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT ID,Value1, Value2
        FROM Table1 

    OPEN cTable1

    --FETCH VARIABLES
    FETCH NEXT FROM cTable1 INTO @ID, @Value1, @Value2

    --LOOP 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (@Value2 = '' OR @Value2 is NULL)
        BEGIN
            --UPDATE Table1.Value2 with next lowest Table1.Value2 > Table1.Value1
            SET @tmpValue = (SELECT MIN(Value1) FROM Table2  WHERE Value1 > @Value1 AND ID = @ID)

            UPDATE Table1 
            SET Value2 = @tmpValue     
            WHERE ID = @ID

            --DELETE AFFECTED ROW FROM Table2
            DELETE FROM Table2 
            WHERE Value1 = @tmpValue AND ID = @ID;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --INSERT ROW IN Table1 WITH ID, Value1 FROM Table2 
            SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table2)
            SET @tmpValue = (SELECT MIN(Value1) FROM Table2 WHERE ID = @ID)

            INSERT INTO Table1(ID, Value1, Value2) 
            VALUES (@ID, @tmpValue, '')

            DELETE FROM Table2 
            WHERE ID = @ID
        END

        --FETCH NEXT VARIABLES
        FETCH NEXT FROM cTable1 INTO @ID, @Value1, @Value2
    END

    --CLOSE THE CURSOR TABLE
    CLOSE cTable1
    DEALLOCATE cTable1
```

There are about 20 thousand rows, so I'm hoping a stored procedure will accomplish all. It's a one-off, so I'm not super concerned about overhead.

Comment: So what if there's another row in `Table2` with `ID1, 111`? And what about `ID1, 444`? What should the end result be in those cases? Irrespective, think sets, not cursors -- `MIN(Value) GROUP BY ID`, `UNION`, `ROW_NUMBER()`, `CROSS APPLY` should come in handy here to build a result in one table. You can then use either `INSERT INTO`, `MERGE` or separate `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements in a transaction to make `Table1` look like that result (and `Table2` can then simply have all its rows deleted). If you haven't used SQL in 10 years, it's a shame you still remembered that cursors exist. :-P

Comment: Is a stored procedure mandatory to achieve your goal? This can easily be done by grabbing the table to a temp table with CASE Statements and INSERT INTO

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I'll need to review MERGE, but I had thought about that as another way I could achieve it.

Comment: @Isaiah3015, no, I am definitely not attached to using a stored procedure. I tried to build it without, initially, but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The basic query needed for an update like this is pretty clear:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET VALUE2 = (
    SELECT MIN(t2.Value1) 
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.Value1 > Table1.Value1 
      AND t2.ID = Table1.ID
    )
```

I would then perform the insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Value1, Value2)
SELECT ID,
    Value1,
    [Empty]
From Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Value1 = t1.Value1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1a
    ON t2.ID = t1a.Id
    AND t2.Value1 = t1a.Value2
WHERE t1.Id IS NULL
    AND t1a.Id IS NULL

DELETE FROM Table2
```

Note that this meets your stated requirements, but may not meet your actual requirements - the comment by @JeroenMostert covers a number of those issues.

Comment: My update section works properly. Sorry for the confusion. I've fixed the wording. I think the UPDATE statement you suggested would not work because it doesn't check whether there's a value in T1.Value2, unless I'm mistaken. Easy enough to insert that check, but is that a better solution than my current UPDATE statement?

I'm very out of practice, so I'll have to refresh on the LEFT JOIN you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The following query seems to produce your desired output:

```
declare @Table1 table (
    Id varchar(30) not null,
    Value1 int null,
    Value2 int null
);

declare @Table2 table (
    Id varchar(30) not null,
    Value int null
);

insert into @Table1 (Id, Value1)
values
    ('ID1', 123),
    ('ID4', 111);

insert into @Table2 (Id, Value)
values
    ('ID1', 224),
    ('ID1', 331),
    ('ID4', 210),
    ('ID4', 551);

select t2.Id,
    case
        when t2.Value = min(t2.Value) over(partition by t1.Id) then t1.Value1
        else t2.Value
    end as [V1],
    case
        when t2.Value = min(t2.Value) over(partition by t1.Id) then t2.Value
    end as [V2]
from @Table1 t1
    left join @Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t1.Value1 < t2.Value;
```

With that in mind, a simple `MERGE` will do the trick:

```
merge @Table1 t
using (
    select t2.Id,
    case
        when t2.Value = min(t2.Value) over(partition by t1.Id) then t1.Value1
        else t2.Value
    end as [V1],
    case
        when t2.Value = min(t2.Value) over(partition by t1.Id) then t2.Value
    end as [V2]
from @Table1 t1
    left join @Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t1.Value1 < t2.Value
) s on s.Id = t.Id and s.V1 = t.Value1
when not matched by target then
    insert (Id, Value1, Value2)
    values (s.Id, s.V1, s.V2)
when matched then
    update set Value2 = s.V2;
```

I might be wrong with some edge cases, but in principle this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;With updateData as (
Select Id , Value1 , row_number() over ( partition by id order by value1 ) rowNumber from table2
)
Update table1 set value2 = t.value1 from updateData t where t.Id = table1.Id and t.rowNumber=1 

;With insertData as(
Select Id , Value1 , row_number() over ( partition by id order by value1 ) rowNumber from table2
)
Insert into table1(id,value1)
Select t.id , t.value1 from insertData t
Where  t.rowNumber>1
```